# Replacing a borrowed variable

Tags: rust

I have a bucket of objects that need to accumulate values. It's protected by an `RwLock`, and as such I also keep around its write lock. I want to keep a single write lock for the duration of the process.

For example:

```
use std::sync::RwLock;

fn main() {
    let locked = RwLock::new(Vec::<u32>::new());

    // this is the entry point for real-world code
    let mut writer = locked.write().unwrap();    

    // copy into 'locked' until it is full (has 4 items)
    for v in 0..100 {
        if writer.len() > 4 {
            // discard 'writer' and 'locked', create anew
            locked = RwLock::new(Vec::<u32>::new());
            writer = locked.write().unwrap();
        }
        writer.push(v);
    }
}
```

While my example operates on fixed data, and so appears to not need the `RwLock` at all, the real code would enter at "real code" and not necessarily exit on the boundary of `locked` becoming "full".

How do I create a new `locked` and `writer` object when needed without the borrow-checker disagreeing?

Comment: I don't see why you have to discard the vector and the lock around it.  Why not just change its size to zero to discard all the data in it?

Comment: I see your disclaimer, but I still don't understand your program. If you hold a writer lock for the duration of the entire program, then a reader lock can never be obtained, thus there isn't really any possibility for multithreading...

Answer (score 3):

I agree [with David Grayson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776577/replacing-a-borrowed-variable#comment64924753_38776577), there's no obvious need to recreate the `RwLock`. Assuming you need the vector after filling it up, use `mem::replace` to switch out the `Vec`:

```
use std::sync::RwLock;
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let locked = RwLock::new(Vec::<u32>::new());
    let mut writer = locked.write().unwrap();    

    for v in 0..100 {
        if writer.len() > 4 {
            let old_vec = mem::replace(&mut *writer, Vec::new());
        }
        writer.push(v);
    }
}
```

If you don't need the `Vec`, then just call [`Vec::clear`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.clear).

Comment: `mem::replace` is documented as not copying any of its parameters, but its source code uses [using copy_non_overlapping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html). I need this code to work with `Drop` and it's unclear when I'm allowed to do that. I created a new question here.

Comment: I think the documentation should say "without cloning" or "without deep-copying". `mem::replace` calls `mem::swap` which correctly uses `mem::forget` in order to prevent extra drops, so you shouldn't have any problems. Anyway the code in this answer doesn't mention `unsafe`, so you know it won't have extra drops without even looking at the source :)