# Replacing a borrowed Arc<RwLock>

Tags: rust

I have some code that stores an object. I have a function that does the legwork of storing that object and returning an Arc of it.

```
struct Something {
    // ...
}

// create a something, returning a locked Arc of it.
fn make_something(&mut self) -> Arc<RwLock<Something>>
{
    let x = Something{};
    let stored = Arc::new(RwLock::new(x));
    // stored is cloned and put into a container in self
    stored.clone()
}
```

Elsewhere, I have code that sometimes needs to get a new make_something, letting the old `Something` get stored elsewhere in `make_something`'s `Self`. However, it gives me scoping problems:

```
fn elsewhere() {
   let mut something_arc = obj.make_something();
   let mut something_locked = something_arc.write().unwrap();
   loop {
      // something_lock is mutated as a Something

      // create a new make something, and start a "transaction"
      something_arc = obj.make_something();
      something_locked = something_arc.write().unwrap();
   }
}
```

The borrow checker is telling me that I can't replace `something_arc` because it's being borrowed by `something_locked`.

How do I replace `something_arc` and `something_locked` with a new `Arc` and associated write lock?

Comment: Could you clarify how this question is different from your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38776577/155423)?

Comment: this one has the Arc, and a function that returns (and keeps reference) to the Arc's contents.

Comment: I can't `std::mem::replace` the Arc because it's being borrowed by the lock. Dropping the lock does nothing.

Comment: Why are you try to `something_arc.write()` if you already have that as `something_locked` ?